# How to find the total number textarea in a form using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, count, textarea

I want to know how many text areas I am using in a form using JQuery as the text areas can be added and deleted. Minimum of two will be there. I know how to find total number of text boxes. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var textareas = jQuery("#FormID textarea").length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)** to achieve this

```
var len = $('<form-selector>').find('textarea').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('textarea').length()
```

Comment: $('textarea').length will grab every textarea in the page. He just wants the ones in the form.

Answer (score 0):

console.log($("form textarea").length);
Will give you the total number of textareas you have in your form

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form>textarea').length;
});
```